# Can I create a new Admin profile and keep all existing files/data?

Tags: macos, user-account

A Mac is being used in a school with an Admin profile of a ex-member of staff. We want to remove any reference to that member of staff but continue to use the Mac in the same way with all existing files.

Can I create a new Admin profile in this way
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3664974

Then delete the unwanted admin profile without losing any files?

Comment: Do you mean profile or user?

Comment: The link is very old and also how to remove a password. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you need to keep user settings and preference, or just files? I'd suggest either create a new user and copy the files; or change the name of the user account, and then search for any other personalised metadata.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. You have many cases where applications have dependencies on the specific user profile. Especially for Mac admin - sysadmin types. Compiled code, secrets in the keychain, hard coded paths, Apple Remote Desktop passwords, scripts, groups and collected data, etc..

However, you should make two backups of this Mac immediately. One backup should be bootable with a reputable software (Carbon Copy Cloner or Super Duper) if you can't use Disk Utility to "restore / clone / asr" a backup. The other should be Time Machine - make sure no files are excluded just to be safe.

Then once you have two backups you can evaluate if you have enough space to make a new generic admin user account and then restore files from the backup to the new account and test.

Do you have a list of software, apps, documents you know or are you a bit in the dark and have more questions than answers yet?

Most consumer apps, data, files care nothing about the home folder or identity of the user, so you can usually do exactly what you seek, however I would urge caution and get a new machine and hire someone and make this their problem to solve / document / manage as part of their duties.